# Displaying all sides of cube - XNA

Tags: c#, xna, textures, blender

I would like to display 6 sides of cube with texture:
[image]

But this is what I get:
[image]

Front, left and top side doesn't display and I have no idea why.

Comment: It looks like you've managed to turn the model inside-out (can sometimes occur when exporting a model between two 3D editing applications). The reason it looks fine in your 3D editing program, and not in your game, is because 3D editors usually show BOTH sides of a mesh, (to make modelling easier), while games only shows the outside of the mesh (to make rendering easier). Of course you can change this to make your game show both sides, but that'd be a waste of performance. So what you're seeing is the 3 other sides of the model. Try inverting the mesh in your 3D editing program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all faces in edit-mode an press Ctrl + N. Your normals will be recalculated and you can see your model properly.

Comment: Just little mention: do it in blender ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need set appropriate RasterizerState ([click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rasterizerstate_members%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx), [click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.rasterizerstate%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx)) before drawing your model.

```
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
```

Using CullCounterClockwise or CullClockwise value depends on how your mesh builded.